# How can I use Cross Platform Input in Unity 2019?

Tags: unity, ios, input, cross-platform

I am trying to use CrossPlatformInput in Unity 2019 to follow this tutorial to use it on iOS:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Auj1mrsfXDE

However, I have no item in the top bar for "Mobile View" like in the tutorial, and I do not know how to enable it. I have Standard Assets imported already. Is there an example project I can download with CrossPlatformInoput that works with iOS or a way for CrossPlatfromInput to work in modern versions of Unity?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding [this](https://github.com/anaisbetts/ViveStarter/blob/master/Assets/Editor/CrossPlatformInput/CrossPlatformInputInitialize.cs) code to my project,
hopefully, it'll fix yours too.

Comment: This is currently a link-only answer, which is risky because links change or rot. If the link ever becomes unavailable, a reader won't be able to learn anything from this answer in its current form. Please edit your answer to include a rough summary of how the code you're suggesting solves OP's problem, so the answer conveys valuable information even before we click the link.